# How is hostname populated in AWS SDK? Getting Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm writing code that won't use AWS profiles - doing everything programatically through the API.

```
Amazon.RegionEndpoint r = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");
Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials creds = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secret);
```

In this example I'll use the CloudWatch API ListMetrics

```
Amazon.CloudWatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient cw = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(creds, r);
...
Amazon.CloudWatch.Model.ListMetricsResponse resp = cw.ListMetrics(lmReq);
```

On one computer this works perfectly.   On another, with the same inputs, it throws an exception with "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

I don't set hostname in either case, but it is being found and used in one case but not the other.

This is using the AWS SDK for .NET and references assemblies for

```
AWSSDK.CloudWatch 
AWSSDK.Core 
AWSSDK.SecurityToken
```

Welcome any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Everything else I had read seemed to implicated the Region.   After some debugging it turns out the region was indeed set wrong (not in the example above), so apparently the Region is the key to the hostname.   The error message is a little unfortunate.